# Bootstrapping database with GreenDAO

Tags: database, bootstrapping, greendao

I've just started using GreenDAO 3.1.0 and I'd like to know how I can initialize the database with some data, i.e. data that will be inserted once and for all further executions of the app.

Thanks in advance

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create and use you own OpenHelper and put data initialization code at the overrided `onCreate` method

```
public static class MyOpenHelper extends DaoMaster.OpenHelper {

    Context mCtx;
    public MyOpenHelper (Context ctx){
        super(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.db_name), null);
        mCtx = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        // Init your data here

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the answer. Where is this class supposed to be? There is DaoMaster but since it is automatically generated, any change won't persist. Also, where and how should I call MyOpenHelper ?
By the way, I use the version with the annotations.

Comment: Use where you are now getting Writable/Readable Database `mMyOpenHelper = new MyOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());db=mMyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();`